# Advice about storing searchable documents with tables and images in MS Access Database

Tags: html, database, ms-access

I have a huge MS Word file I use for personal notes but I want it to be more flexible. The file is made from short articles (600 words) with date, title, sometimes a table or some images. I came up with the idea of separating the single articles an put them in Access, to extract them from the database with queries, add tags, sort chronologically.
One big question is: which format should I use? I tried Access 2010 Rich Text Edit but it doesn't show tables, and I don't know where to store images. My idea is to store images outside the file.

Another thing I tried is to store the files as HTML in the database directory, but when I try to add some interface functionality I encounter problems with the most trivial things, like making VBA open the associated file. I don't like storing outside Access also because I don't have full-text search.

The primary requisite for this application is that it must not be cumbersome: it's a prototype I want to use to see if my model of storing notes works, so I don't want to spend a month programming an user interface, and if I note any defect at runtime I must be able to switch to design mode and fix it in minutes. If I want to write something, i don't have to worry about HTML syntax but I want to be able to add some simple table or image.
What I finally search is a HTML viewer in Access interface that receives an HTML string (composed by a query) and displays it.

At this moment I'm considering to remain with my MS Word file because switching seems too complex, although I don't like the sequentiality of articles and the hierarchy of chapters/subchapters, which made me think about this Idea.

Comment: I do not think that MS Access is going to give you the simplicity you require. You can add a good deal of information to Word documents using existing and custom tags. For the most part, these are visible in folder listings.

Comment: If you have Windows 7, you can do a lot with search (http://windows.microsoft.com/en-IE/windows7/Advanced-tips-for-searching-in-Windows) or with XP up, build fairly fancy search criteria with script (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb231256(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Windows 7 search is unreliable (at least it happened to me that it didn't find items that were there). I don't trust binary files (especially closed ones) so I must escape Word's world as soon as possible. I thought about keeping different files in a format I have yet to decide and search them with a custom Delphi 7 or Python simple app. Maybe I can use HTML with a custom very simple and lightweight editor, making it in Delphi 7, just not to spend time writing <p>, <html>, <table>, <tb>, <img>, and so on.

Comment: But what about chronological order? To sort files I can't rely on modified/created date, it can be changed by anything (like backup software), so I need at least a little database and the procedure would look like: 1) have idea 2) write it and save to file (which name should I give to the file?) 3) insert the entry in the database, possibly entering wrong filename. Result: the idea is lost or difficult to retrieve

Comment: Where I see things getting complicated is adding such a variety of items (formatted text, tables, images) to a table in a database and allowing editing. I am not sure that any database is going to be simple without a great deal of work to make it so.

Comment: I am thinking (if I start this project) to create a Delphi 7 app to facilitate article and metadata entry (date, tags, and which will come to my mind developing this), with small HTML editor (just for tables/images), which saves files (readable and searchable with win/linux/whatever) and maybe helps searching, ordering and maybe connecting them. Do you see any flaws?

Comment: Yes, I am afraid I see the system getting gradually out of synch.

Comment: It occurs to me that a content management system (CMS) may be what you want. Your data can be set up as a small website even on your own computer. Dates of additions and changes can be logged.

Comment: This is really useful. Can you address me to some lightweight CMS you know?

Comment: You might like to consider Wordpress and also see here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/557341/best-cms-for-a-magazine

Comment: I've had a look to XAMPP + Wordpress and it looks like I'm going in the (unwanted) direction of binding data and configuration, since on every computer I'd want to read my "knowledge-base" I'd have to install MySQL, Apache and configure them. Do you know a local standalone CMS?

Comment: No, I don't, but I see several when I do a search, also standlone wikis such as http://www.tiddlywiki.com/ You might like to ask another question, though possibly in a different stackexchange forum.

Comment: I think I solved the problem with Moinmoin Desktop. Thank you for giving me the right keywords to look for. What I meant but I didn't realize was that I need a "personal wiki".

Comment: Switched to DokuWiki from Moinmon because: 1) it has namespaces 2) can run on a standalone php server (QuickPHP by Zach Saw) so can run virtually everywere and can also be hosted to any server with php 3) has quote blocks (Moinmoin doesn't) 4) Keeps media versions 5) section editing

Comment: Switched server to Uniform Server because QuickPhp was too basic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to all those problems was [Evernote](http://www.evernote.com/), which is like a Wiki you can edit quickly also from a smartphone, with or without an internet connection, which syncs to a master version on an Evernote server and without the constraint of having to invent a title for every page/idea.

Answer (score 0):

If I had a huge Word document like yours, I'd probably split it into individual files and use something like [dtSearch](http://www.dtsearch.com/).

Comment: Splitting between files is what I've done before and it's not a good idea: I decided to put all things in a file because I want to access informations without thinking, only pressing CTRL+F and the word I need. 

I could make distinct files and search them, but I don't trust Windows 7 search very much (sometimes it has proven to me not to be reliable, not finding what I know is there) and I don't like installing new software. In this case I would not know which format to use (no binary formats anymore, please) to include images/tables.

Comment: But you *are* considering writing your own Delphi 7 app to do this. dtSearch has a 30-day eval version. It will work with just about any text *or* binary format you can come up with, and it will probably work with your big, single Word document without any changes. Read about it before you dismiss it.

Comment: Yes, but I have to pay for it and I think my case can be solved with free software. I think the CMS alternative proposed earlier is very interesting as it may change radically (and in a better way) my way to organize things